# Unit test a Mutated List

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a function that is intended to mutate a list.

I wanted to build some unit tests for this function, but I don't know how to test for a change in values when the function doesn't return something...

For example:

```
def square_list(lst):
    """
    Input: a list of numbers
    Doesn't return anything, mutates given list
    """

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        lst[i] **= 2
```

Obviously I can build a unit test for this, but without a retun value it won't work

```
import unittest
from square_list import square_list

class TestSquareList(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_square_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(square_list([1, 2]), [1, 4])
        self.assertEqual(square_list([0]), [0])
```

How would you test this function mutates the input to the function appropriately?

Comment: Did you mean ```self.assertEqual(square_list([0]), [0])```

Comment: Yes sorry, edited it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it up like this:

```
import unittest
from square_list import square_list

class TestSquareList(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_square_list(self):
        provided = [1, 2]
        expected = [1, 4]
        square_list(provided)   # mutates provided
        self.assertEqual(provided, expected)
```